# Rails adding /#/ to root url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes

Probably a simple question, but I'm using Rails 6 with webpacker and getting this issue where my root url is coming up as /#/ instead of /. If I try to go to localhost:3000, it automatically redirects to localhost:3000/#/ and all my other routes go through that. I can't find anything that I've done differently from a typical Rails app in this project that would cause the routes to work like this.

I'd like to get it to a clean localhost:3000/ so it looks better and I believe the /#/ is messing up a tags with fragment hrefs, making them redirect to the index page.

Edit:
Adding in the output from `rails routes`

```
                          api_session GET    /api/session(.:format)                                                                   api/sessions#show {:format=>:json}
                                      DELETE /api/session(.:format)                                                                   api/sessions#destroy {:format=>:json}
                                      POST   /api/session(.:format)                                                                   api/sessions#create {:format=>:json}
                            api_users GET    /api/users(.:format)                                                                     api/users#index {:format=>:json}
                                      POST   /api/users(.:format)                                                                     api/users#create {:format=>:json}
                             api_user GET    /api/users/:id(.:format)                                                                 api/users#show {:format=>:json}
                                      PATCH  /api/users/:id(.:format)                                                                 api/users#update {:format=>:json}
                                      PUT    /api/users/:id(.:format)                                                                 api/users#update {:format=>:json}
                        api_campaigns GET    /api/campaigns(.:format)                                                                 api/campaigns#index {:format=>:json}
                                      POST   /api/campaigns(.:format)                                                                 api/campaigns#create {:format=>:json}
                         api_campaign GET    /api/campaigns/:id(.:format)                                                             api/campaigns#show {:format=>:json}
                                      PATCH  /api/campaigns/:id(.:format)                                                             api/campaigns#update {:format=>:json}
                                      PUT    /api/campaigns/:id(.:format)                                                             api/campaigns#update {:format=>:json}
                                      DELETE /api/campaigns/:id(.:format)                                                             api/campaigns#destroy {:format=>:json}
                    api_campaign_subs GET    /api/campaign_subs(.:format)                                                             api/campaign_subs#index {:format=>:json}
                                      POST   /api/campaign_subs(.:format)                                                             api/campaign_subs#create {:format=>:json}
                     api_campaign_sub DELETE /api/campaign_subs/:id(.:format)                                                         api/campaign_subs#destroy {:format=>:json}
                       api_characters GET    /api/characters(.:format)                                                                api/characters#index {:format=>:json}
                                      POST   /api/characters(.:format)                                                                api/characters#create {:format=>:json}
                        api_character GET    /api/characters/:id(.:format)                                                            api/characters#show {:format=>:json}
                                      PATCH  /api/characters/:id(.:format)                                                            api/characters#update {:format=>:json}
                                      PUT    /api/characters/:id(.:format)                                                            api/characters#update {:format=>:json}
                                      DELETE /api/characters/:id(.:format)                                                            api/characters#destroy {:format=>:json}
                          api_invites POST   /api/invites(.:format)                                                                   api/invites#create {:format=>:json}
                           api_invite PATCH  /api/invites/:id(.:format)                                                               api/invites#update {:format=>:json}
                                      PUT    /api/invites/:id(.:format)                                                               api/invites#update {:format=>:json}
                                      DELETE /api/invites/:id(.:format)                                                               api/invites#destroy {:format=>:json}
                                 root GET    /                                                                                        static_pages#root
```

development.log doesn't have anything particularly telling in it either.

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2020-04-19 16:00:18 -0400
Processing by StaticPagesController#root as HTML
```

Then some database calls

```
Rendered api/users/_user.json.jbuilder (Duration: 140.1ms | Allocations: 20249)
  Rendered static_pages/root.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 150.1ms | Allocations: 21250)
Completed 200 OK in 217ms (Views: 204.9ms | ActiveRecord: 11.7ms | Allocations: 28894)
```

Comment: What are you seeing in the development log when you open the page?  Just to be totally clear, this is when the page loads, not after you have clicked on something right?  Can you post the output of `rake routes` please?

Comment: Are you using any js framework that uses a js router? check the browser's network that, I think it tells you which code initiated the request

Comment: Can you share the API controller handling that action, it looks like you hit the API route but then the root gets rendered, I bet it is happening on that process.

Comment: @RockwellRice I'm running a basic StaticPagesController to use React for the frontend.
```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
    def root; end
end
```

Comment: Looking at these posts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49240231/removing-from-hashrouter  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually/36623117#36623117 It appears my problem is actually with <HashRouter> in my react router having a route that doesn't match with the server. Will look into it more and see if I can find out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually did figure this out in a way. The problem was that I was using HashRouter which uses hashed content in the URL for frontend routing, but never sends that information to the server.

I resolved it by switching to BrowserRouter and implementing a catch-all route to reroute everything to the /* path.

However, I know that in the past I've made single page apps with HashRouter that did not add the # to the url and worked perfectly fine with the backend. I'm not sure what I was doing differently this time or if perhaps it's because of later versions of Rails or React.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using vue-router

default mode for the vue-router is hash(#) mode as it uses the URL hash to simulate a full URL so that the page won’t be reloaded when the URL changes.

To get rid of the hash mode, you can use the router’s history mode, which leverages the `history.pushState` API to achieve URL navigation without a page reload. And add -> `mode: 'history'`.

example:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [...]
})
```